# How do I select the inputted text of a text field?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm adding interactivity to a form.

Here is a snippet of the HTML:

```
<label for="name" id="nameLabel">Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
```

There is a button at the bottom of the form, 'Register'. If the button is pressed and the Name field is empty, I want to add an alert message, reminding the user to enter their name. I want to do this by amending the label.

I am having trouble trying to select the inputted text of the text-field. Seeing as it's not value or innerHTML? How do I select it?

This is the code I have so far:

```
    // Form validation. Display error messages and don't let the user submit the form if any of these validation errors exist:
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Name field can't be empty
    var nameInput = document.getElementById("name");
    var nameLabel = document.getElementById("nameLabel");

    if(nameInput.value === "") {
        nameLabel.innerHTML = "Name: (please provide name)";
        nameLabel.style.color = "red";
    }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: how to get value of text input field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/javascript-how-to-get-value-of-text-input-field)

Comment: "Seeing as it's not value" - It is value.

Comment: why there is `???` after value?

Comment: .value doesn't work though.

I get a flash of error in the console but it's too quick to catch what it is.

I was just using ??? to make it clear where I was struggling

Comment: Right click in your console and select "preserve contents across page reloads" or a similar sounding option.

Comment: Thanks, I got rid of the error but it's still not working right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .value to get the value of input field and put `css` value `red` in inverted comma as `nameLabel.style.color = "red";` Also since you have a

```
<button type ="submit">submit</button>
```

you need to stop you page from refreshing. Use `e.preventDefault();` for this in your event handler

The flash of error that you get while in console is that red is not defined which it isn't since its a string and you need to give it in `""`.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Name field can't be empty
    var nameInput = document.getElementById("name");
    var nameLabel = document.getElementById("nameLabel");

    if(nameInput.value === "") {
        nameLabel.innerHTML = "Name: (please provide name)";
        nameLabel.style.color = "red";
    }
});
```

```html
<label for="name" id="nameLabel">Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
<button>Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, I can see that works in the code snippet but it's not working in my code for some strange reason

Comment: Yup! Very confused, my code is identical to yours right now

Comment: Okay you said you are creating these input fields dynamically. May I know how are you doing that, could be a issue because of that

Comment: I've edited the code in my original question to reflect how my JS looks right now.

Comment: Do one thing add a console.log(nameInput) inside you .click event and see if you are getting the desired result and then we can see how to retrieve its value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122256/discussion-between-gloopit-and-shubham-khatri).

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Name field can't be empty
    var nameInput = document.getElementById("name");
    var nameLabel = document.getElementById("nameLabel");
 console.log("\"" + nameInput.value + "\"");
    if(nameInput.value.length == 0) {
        nameLabel.innerHTML = "Name: (please provide name)";
        nameLabel.style.color = "red";
    }
});
```

```html
<label for="name" id="nameLabel">Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
<button>Submit</button>
```